# Flexible equation, align, multline environment

Tags: equations, align, multline

I'm looking for a command (say `\foo{}`) or pair of commands (say `\foos`, `\fooe`) that behave like:

`equation` environment if there is no `\\` nor `&`

`multline` if there is a single `\\`

`align` if there are both `&` and `\\`

Also, automatically switches between the `*` variants if there is no `\label` command.

The commands should be compatible with usual packages (`amsmath` etc), and should support the usual `\tag`, `\label`, `\ref` commands.  Just to be clear, using it should not slow down compilation by any perceptible amount.

Bonus gratitude if you also give me a command to switch the behavior of `\[` `\]` from the usual one to the above one, back-and-forth in a paper.

I am constantly switching between the three environments and it is really annoying. Thanks!

**Note:** I am telling LaTeX where to break the equation. All I want is LaTeX to be smart enough to use the appropriate environment!

Comment: I meant double back-slash, but it didn't show.

Comment: A tip: you can enclose TeX code in back quotes as I've done in my edit.

Comment: It should be possible to define a custom environment that parses its contents to determine which one is appropriate based on the algorithm you describe and then pass the environment `\BODY` to the appropriate environment, at least for simple cases. But that is beyond my skill set.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there isn't such a "do-it-all" environment. Each one of `equation`, `multline`, `align` and `gather` (you forgot about this one) solves a different problem caused by different sets of math mode material to display.

Breaking math mode material requires judgment that a machine can't have.

There are packages such as **nath** and **breqn** that try to automatize this process, but my opinion is that there's no easy algorithm to do breaking properly, because it requires to *look* at the result.

However, here it is a working `doitall` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ,xstring}
\newif\iflabel
\newif\ifdbs
\newif\ifamp
\NewEnviron{doitall}{%
  \noexpandarg
  \expandafter\IfSubStr\expandafter{\BODY}{\label}{\labeltrue}{\labelfalse}%
  \expandafter\IfSubStr\expandafter{\BODY}{\\}{\dbstrue}{\dbsfalse}%
  \expandafter\IfSubStr\expandafter{\BODY}{&}{\amptrue}{\ampfalse}%
  \iflabel\def\doitallstar{}\else\def\doitallstar{*}\fi
  \ifdbs
    \ifamp
      \def\doitallname{align}%
    \else
      \def\doitallname{multline}%
    \fi
  \else
    \def\doitallname{equation}
  \fi
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\begin{\doitallname\doitallstar}%
    \noexpand\BODY
    \noexpand\end{\doitallname\doitallstar}%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}
Numbered

\begin{doitall}
a=b\label{1}
\end{doitall}
\begin{doitall}
a\\b\label{2}
\end{doitall}
\begin{doitall}
a&=b\label{3}\\
c&=dxxxxx
\end{doitall}

Now no numbers

\begin{doitall}
a=b
\end{doitall}
\begin{doitall}
a\\b
\end{doitall}
\begin{doitall}
a&=b\\
c&=dxxxxx
\end{doitall}
\end{document}
```

I can understand your desire of a do-it-all environment; but you're losing information.

If you want to use `\[` and `\]` as delimiters, just say

```
\def\[#1\]{\begin{doitall}#1\end{doitall}}
```

in the preamble. Switching the meaning of `\[...\]` back and forth is completely useless, of course.

### Limitations

You can't use `aligned` or `gathered` environments inside the `doitall` environment, as these have `&` and `\\` inside them. It's of course impossible to use also the `split` environment.

Comment: Thanks (grazie) for the pointers. However you are misinterpreting my question. I *am* telling LaTeX where to break the equation. All I want is LaTeX to be smart enough to use the appropriate environment! One can write e.g. a Perl script that does the job. Can't it be done automatically by LaTeX?

Comment: @EmanueleViola I've asked the moderator to remove the $100 offer, which is quite inappropriate here. The solution is actually rather easy; but it's not something I would use.

Comment: THANK YOU! You just made my day. And of course I stand by my previous $100 offer. I am really glad to see this solved and that the solution isn't complicated.